# How to redeploy artifact release to nexus without "400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request." answer?

Tags: java, jenkins, build, nexus, sonatype

Ok, I have an artifact release in version x.y.z and I want to redeploy it automatically without changing it's version (I can't change the version!).

The artifact it's divided in three **jars** that are generated separately. So I have:

- Artifact GUI
- Artifact Core 32bits
- Artifact Core 64bits

They all have the same version. When I'm deploying a SNAPSHOT version I have no problem. But when I deploy the release **nexus** throws this error inside **jenkins** console:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: 
http://myNexus/nexus/content/repositories/releases/my/package/project/x.y.z/jar-file-x.y.z.jar.
Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
```

Of course the problem it's that I'm deploying more than one release artifact in a version that obviously need to be unique. But I really **need** to deploy it that way. Is there a way to force nexus to accept a release more than once?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to update the Deployment Policy for the release repository. Instead of "Disable Redeploy" it should be set to "Allow Redeploy".
More information on this topic can be found in the [sonatype nexus book](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-manage-repo.html#fig-repo-config-hosted).

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, because disabling this policy will affect all repository artifacts. Continuous delivery isn't made to be used like this. Do you know a way to enable redeploy only for this artifact? This would be very very **usefull**.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But enabling it for only a single artifact will imo not work - in Sonatype Nexus you are setting the deployment policy at repository level.

Comment: Years after this someone upvoted my question and I came here to check the answers cause I don't remember what I did at that time hahaha but I noticed that I forget to upvote your answer. Thanks for trying to help at that time :)